# Is this an error in Oppenheim and Schafer's Discrete-Time Signal Processing?

Tags: sampling, analog-to-digital, digital-to-analog

In *Discrete-Time Signal Processing* by Alan V. Oppenheim and Ronald W. Schafer (3rd Ed.), in **Figure 4.47** the input of D/A converter is $\hat{y}[n]$ but later in **Figure 4.64** the input of D/A converter is $\hat{x}[n]$. Is this a mistake?

Normally, based on **Figure 4.47** $\hat{y}[n]$ is the output of the discrete-time system with input $\hat{x}[n]$.

Answer (score 2):

It is not a mistake. In section 4.8.4 the authors introduce the reconstruction of $x_r(t)$ from $x[n]$ in equation $(4.140)$; and in the paragraph below, the authors consider the input sequence and output signal to the ideal D/C converter as $x[n]$ and $x_r(t)$ respectively, as shown below
$$x[n]{\longrightarrow}\boxed{\textit{Ideal D/C converter}}{\longrightarrow}x_r(t)$$
Which will be more in line with the last input-output block of **Figure 4.47**(a) shown as
$$\cdots \quad y[n]{\longrightarrow}\boxed{\textit{D/C}}{\longrightarrow}y_r(t)$$

To clarify, the extension from *ideal D/C converter* to the D/A and their corresponding maths with inputs-outputs relations and the figures, please consider reading the full section 4.8.4 with emphasis on the change of notation just after equation $(4.140)$.

Comment: I  do not agree. The inputs and outputs of two figures are not consistent.

Comment: @DSPinfinity what do you mean exactly with *not consistent*? The change of notation?

Comment: Ie, the inputs and outputs of two figures are not consistent. $\hat{x}[n]$  in Fig. 4.47 is input to the discrete-time system but in Fig.4.62 and 4.64  it is the same signal in D/A.   $\hat{x}[n]$  is processed by  the discrete-time system  and  hence it will change unless the   discrete-time system is unit gain.

Comment: @DSPinfinity, I've added an edit. Please consider visiting section 4.8.4 of the book.

Comment: I understand in terms of notation but since Fig 4.62 and 4.64 are parts in Fig 4.47, it makes very confusing and hence everything including notation must be consistent.

Comment: moreover, after eq.4.145 it is said x[n]=x_a(nT) where x_a(t) is a signal in A/D in Figure 4.47. The book is horrible to follow due to these notations.

Comment: @DSPinfinity the book is **not** horrible to follow, it’s one of the best in the field!

Comment: the notation of all signals  in the D/A block should be y to be consistent with Fig 4.47.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117399/discussion-between-dspinfinity-and-gilles).